# Queue node.js callbacks

Tags: node.js, queue

I am using node.js along with express. I have a REST API open which is

```
app.get('/pushtoqueue/:id', function(req, res){
  //do something
  callFunction(data, function(){
    //Do sequential execution
  }); 
}
```

When REST gets requests it calls `callFunction`, where this functions needs to be executed in sequential way. Which means, when REST gets called 1st time request should be processed, while `callFunction` is in execution if another request arrives for `callFunction` that should be queued until 1st execution is completed and so on for more future request.

How can I achieve this in node.js. Is there any way to queue requests?

Comment: Not sure to understand what is the problem here. Nodejs works in a single thread, by default everything is queued. In your example, you should have to send a response from within the `callFunction` callback, if you want more control, you could use asyncjs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a queue that autoexecutes their elements. If the queue is empty, when you push the first task then it is immediately executed. While the task is being executed another task might be pushed, so instead of being executed it is just enqueued.

I have a module that does exactly this: [deferred-queue](https://github.com/gagle/node-deferred-queue)